# iron:router beforeAction login AND data: function?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm using the standard iron:router pattern for ensuring that a user is authenticated before accessing a route:

```
authenticatedController = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    if ( Meteor.user() ){
      var route = Router.current().route.getName();
      this.next();
    } else this.render('login');
})
```

This works very well for unparameterized routes for example:

```
Router.route("profile",{
  name: "profile",
  controller: 'authenticatedController'
});
```

When I try to extend this pattern to a parameterized route, for example:

```
Router.route('/foo/:id',{
  name: 'foo',
  controller: 'authenticatedController',
  data: function(){ return myCollection.findOne({ _id: this.params.id }); } }
});
```

1. It works if the user is already logged in
2. I get the 404 page if the user is **not** logged in

It seems that *beforeAction* runs *after* the data function. Since *myCollection* doesn't publish any documents until the user is logged in iron:router decides the route doesn't exist.

The only time I want a 404 is if the collection search doesn't return anything.

Comment: did you try on the Router.configure?  `notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',` and the hook `Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'profile'});`

Comment: Thanks Ethann - I have `notFoundTemplate: 'notFound` - that's how my 404 gets shown. I haven't tried `Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'profile'});` because I actually want a 404 if the id doesn't exist (or someone leaves some of it behind when cutting/pasting the URL)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following pattern which works well for me:

```
//I create a hook for authentication
var userAuthHook = function() {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        this.next();
    } else {
        this.redirect('/login');
    }
};

//I apply this hook to all routes except login
Router.onBeforeAction(userAuthHook, {
    except: ['login']
});

//if I want a 404 error, I put it in a onAfterAction callback
Router.route('/message/:_id', {
    name: 'message',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [...];
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
        //we wait for the 'waitOn' data to be ready
        if(this.ready()) {
            var message = Messages.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
            if(!message) {
                //if there is no corresponding message we render the 404 template
                this.render('error404');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this will work for you too.

Comment: Merci Guilllaume. Using `onAfterAction` to handle 404s is very useful. However your pattern doesn't set the data context for the template. I still have to set the data context in the template helper rather than get it from the router. Also if you do `this.redirect('login')` in your `beforeAction` hook rather than `this.render('login') then the user won't be taken to the intended route after login.

Answer (score 0):

I would try either https://github.com/zimme/meteor-iron-router-auth/ or `Router.go` instead of `this.render`

Comment: Thanks Loren, I'll give it a shot!